# Код на Javascript не работает

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такой код выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at script.js:21

```
var input = 'javascript is awesome';
var output = input.split('');
for (var i = 0; i <= output.length; i++) {
  if (output[i].indexOf('a') != -1) {
    output[i] = '4';
  } else if (output[i].indexOf('e') != -1) {
    output[i] = '3';
  } else if (output[i].indexOf('o') != -1) {
    output[i] = '0';
  }
}
output.join('');
alert(output);
```

Comment: output.length выдает количество элементов в массиве, при это индекс последнего элемента равен output.length - 1 и у вас идет выход за границы массива

Answer (score 1):

Кроме неверного условия цикла(что уже было указано в соседних ответах), в вашем коде есть еще, как минимум одна проблема:

```
output.join('');
```

не меняет значение переменной `output` (как вам почему то кажется), а возвращает новое значение-строку.

---

По-хорошему, вместо вашего "страшненького" цикла, можно использовать одну единственную функцию [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var input = 'javascript is awesome';
var output = input.split('').map(function (char) {
    switch (char) {
        case 'a':
            return 4;
        case 'e':
            return 3;
        case 'o':
            return 0;
        default:
            return char;
    }
}).join('');

alert(output);
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/e8pc9uas/) на JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно не так:

```
i <= output.length;
```

а так:

```
i < output.length;
```

Потому что отсчет ведется с нуля и в итоге получается вы выходите за границы массива на 1 символ.

Answer (score 0):

`(var i = 0; i <= output.length; i++)` - тут проблема, а именно в `<=`. Вы от первого элемента 0, до элемента output.length. Так как отсчет начинатся с 0, то элемента с индексом output.length не существует. Используйте `<`

```js
var input = 'javascript is awesome';
var output = input.split('');
for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  if(output[i].indexOf('a') != -1) {
      output[i] = '4';
  } else if (output[i].indexOf('e') != -1) {
      output[i] = '3';
  } else if (output[i].indexOf('o') != -1) {
      output[i] = '0';
  }
}
output.join('');
alert(output);
```